# Issue with Mac RDP clients connecting to Server 2008 if change password at next logon checked

Tags: windows-server-2008, mac, rdp, password-policy

I have a weird issue I haven't been able to figure out (primarily because I don't have a Mac to play with). When a user is connecting into our Windows Server 2008 and 2008 R2 servers with local user accounts if their account is set to force user to change password at next logon (which happens monthly by policy) Mac users can't successfully connect in.

The Macs will connect in and get the message that they need to change the password and will put in a new password. However that's as far as it goes, the password doesn't actually change, just a warning they have entered an incorrect username or password. If they then pop over to a PC (virt or phys) they login in change the password and then can use the Mac like normal.

This occurs both on and off VPN, different servers on different subnets.

Macs are 10.5 and above, with at least RDP 2

Just thought I'd drop a line here as google searches haven't been very helpful while I hunt down a mac to play with.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same here. If Force Password Change is checked and the user accesses via Mac RDP they get an incorrect credential message, but if they switch to a Windows machine they can change the password without issues.